# Export an image using Images in Julia

Tags: arrays, image, julia

Suppose I have an `m`-by-`n`-by-`3` array of `Uint8` which represents an image, where an RGB colorspace is assumed. I would like to export it as a 24-bit-per-pixel PNG image using the `Images` package. How can I do this?

I naively tried to apply `imwrite` to a randomly-generated raw array, as follows:

```
imwrite(rand(Uint8,300,300,3),"test.png")
```

However, this gave an error saying "mapinfo has no method mapinfo...".

Likewise, using

```
imwrite(rand(Float32,300,300,3),"test.png")
```

gave an error saying that it can't infer the colorspace, and that I should use an `AbstractImage` type instead. So presumably the `Images` package is not comfortable assuming that an `m`-by-`n`-by-`3` array is automatically an RGB image (the `Images` documentation cites complications due to the existence of 3D and 4D image types as the reason for not automatically inferring this).

How can I export a numeric array as an image? Can it be done directly, or do I need to create a  wrapper for the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

`imwrite` (and `imread`) are have been deprecated since version 0.5 of Images package (October 2015). They are replaced by `save` (and `load`).

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

for BW:

```
   imwrite(grayim(rand(300,300)),"test.png")
```

for color:

```
   imwrite(convert(Image,rand(300,300,3)),"test.png")
```

worked for me (I have Julia v0.4 and Images.jl v0.4.0)

Comment: Works for me, too, and just for reference it exports the image as an 8-bit-per-color-channel (24-bit depth) image. Any idea how to adapt it to work for `Uint8` arrays too? In any case, the floating-point array conversion is basically what I need, so thanks!

Comment: Works for Uint8 too, just use `rand(Uint8, 300, 300)` in the `grayim` example above. In general you'll be happier if you use `grayim`, `colorim`, or `convert` if you're constructing images from plain arrays.

Comment: does `imwrite` still exist? I can't seem to use it after writing `using Images`, and I can't find any documentation or mention of it on the web.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @WillBrickner Thanks, seems you are right. `imwrite` doesn't exist. I'll try to find the replacement method to update this answer.

Comment: @WillBrickner OK, `imwrite` and `imread` are now `save` and `load`.