# Export a Uint8 array as an image using Images in Julia

Tags: image, julia

I [recently asked how to convert `Float32` or `Uint8` arrays into images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706309/export-an-image-using-images-in-julia) in the `Images` package. I got an answer for the `Float32` case, but am still having trouble figuring out how to save a `Uint8` array.

As an example, let's create a random `Uint8` array using the traditional Matlab scheme where the dimensions are `(m,n,3)`:

```
array = rand(Uint8, 50, 50, 3);
img = convert(Image, array);
```

Using the same approach as works for the `Float32` case,

```
imwrite(img, "out.png")
```

fails with message

> ERROR: method 'mapinfo' has no method matching mapinfo(::Type{ImageMagick}, ::Image{Uint8, 3, Image{Uint8, 3, Array{Uint8, 3}}}).

I checked the documentation, [and it says](https://github.com/timholy/Images.jl/blob/master/doc/function_reference.md)

> If data encodes color information along one of the dimensions of the array (as opposed to using a ColorValue array, from the Color.jl package), be sure to specify the "colordim" and "colorspace" in properties.

However, inspecting the `img` object previously created shows that it has `colordim = 3` and `colorspace = RGB` already set up, so this can't be the problem.

I then searched the documentation for all instances of `MapInfo`. In [core.md](https://github.com/timholy/Images.jl/blob/master/doc/core.md) there is one occurrence:

> scalei: a property that controls default contrast scaling upon display. This should be a MapInfo value, to be used for setting the contrast upon display. In the absence of this property, the range 0 to 1 will be used.

But there was no information on what exactly a `MapInfo` object is, so I looked further, and in [function_reference.md](https://github.com/timholy/Images.jl/blob/master/doc/function_reference.md) it says:

> Here is how to directly construct the major concrete MapInfo types:
>
> MapNone(T), indicating that the only form of scaling is conversion to type T. This is not very safe, as values "wrap around": for example, converting 258 to a Uint8 results in 0x02, which would look dimmer than 255 = 0xff.
>
> ...

and some other examples. So I tried to specify `scalei = MapNone(Uint8)` as follows:

```
img2 = Image(img, colordim = 3, colorspace = "RGB", scalei = MapNone(Uint8));
imwrite(img, "out.png")
```

but got the same error again.

How do you encode `Uint8` image data using `Images` in Julia?

Comment: I did actually leave a comment at the old issue you linked to. But the response from juliohm is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert back and forth between arrays of primitive types such as `UInt8` and arrays of [color types](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/ColorTypes.jl). These conversions are achieved in a unified way via two functions: `colorview` and `channelview`.

### Example

Convert array of `UInt8` to array of `RGB`:

```
arr = rand(UInt8, 3, 50, 50)
img = colorview(RGB, arr / 255)
```

Convert back to channel view:

```
channelview(img)
```

#### Notes

- In this example the RGB color type requires that the entries of the array live in `[0,1]` as floating point. I manually converted `UInt8` to `Float64` using an explicit division by `255`. There is probably a more generic way of achieving this result with `reinterpret` or some other function in Images.jl
- The `colorview` and `channelview` functions assume that the channel dimension is the first dimension of the array. You can use `permutedims` in case your channels live in a different dimension, or use some function in Images.jl (maybe `reinterpretc`?) to do it efficiently without memory copies.

Comment: This answer is outdated as of 2018 - colorim has been deprecated and removed in recent versions of julia. See https://github.com/JuliaImages/Images.jl/issues/697
Still looking for a new answer to this question!